# Google cloud function with puppeteer does not work, even though it works in firebase functions emulator

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I made this function. It works correctly in firebase functions emulator, but when i use firebase deploy --only functions, I am getting errors like the ones on the picture. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is my package.json

```html
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions -P default",
    "serve-dev": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions -P staging",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions -P default",
    "deploy-dev": "firebase deploy --only functions -P staging",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^1.7.1",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.3.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
    "golang": "^0.1.5-stable",
    "node-fetch": "^2.5.0",
    "puppeteer": "5.4.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.2"
  },
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  }
}
```

Here is the code of the function, it is in TypeScript, which after building becomes js ofc:

```js
export const  RecurringTradingUpdate = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('website');
  await page.waitFor(2000);
  
  //await page.click('input[type=password]');
  await page.click('#inputPassword');
  await page.keyboard.sendCharacter('password')
  //await page.click('button[type=submit]');
  await page.click('#clickPassword');
  
  await page.waitFor(2000);
  
  //await page.click('button[type=submit]');
  await page.click('#submit');
  await page.waitFor(120000)

  response.send("All done.")

});
```

[image]

Comment: Generally, you should not post code as image (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please replace sensitive data with some placeholder values and post the code as text to help other to replicate the issue. In this situation it would be good to add `package.json` as well.

Comment: That's an error in your client app code, not in your function.  You should do a web search on that error message to learn about CORS and the limitations on web browser network access.

Comment: This error 408 you should check in function logs ex. in Firebase console. I tried to implement something on my side had the same error and in the log it was due to timeout.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)